# Tag vs class vs label vs category

Tags: classification, terminology

What is the difference between a *tag*, a *class*, a *label*, and a *category* in the context of supervised classification? If these four terms are field-dependent, I am mostly interested in natural language processing.

Comment: And don't forget this choice: the dependent variable